# Cloudfoundry: Restage an application without downtime

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I googled more time but lost. Expecting an answer or ideas to solve this.

`cf restart-app-instance` helps for restarts but I have to restage for environment variable updates.

Is there any way to do instance level `restage` in Cloudfoundry?

PS: I even checked if there any clone option scale up and scale down original without downtime but no luck either.

Answer (score 2):

We used this particular plugin https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/cf-plugin-bg-restage .

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

**bg-restage** will not give any downtime .

https://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/

> Perform a zero-downtime restage of an application over the top of an
>   old one (highly inspired by autopilot)

```
install:
cf install-plugin -r CF-Community "bg-restage"
company:Orange
homepage:https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/cf-plugin-bg-restage
author:Arthur Halet - arthur.halet@orange.com
platforms:osx , win64 , win32 , linux64 , linux32
```

cf bg-restage is mostly for those who don't want to redeploy an app with source code. It was initially created to restage automatically all apps in a Cloud Foundry when a new buildpack has been released with security patch.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to do a blue-green deployment. 
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html

Comment: Yes, we use BLUE GREEN deployment but this is a different scenario. thanks anyways!

Comment: The question is titled "Restage an application without downtime", blue green is currently the best way to do that. There is an experimental feature that also addresses this too :- https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/zero-downtime.html